# Forcing a Task to Wait Before Updating the UI in Continuation

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, wait

All, I want to update a `ToolStripMenu` to show an `SqlConnection` failure. I want the error message to display for some time `timeToWaitMs` (in milli-second) and then refresh the UI back to an okay state after some time and some operations. Currently I am doing (with some un-necessary details removed)

```
public void ShowErrorWithReturnTimer(string errorMessage, int timeToWaitMs = 5000)
{
    // Update the UI (and images/colors etc.).
    this.toolStripLabelState.Text = errorMessage;

    // Wait for timeToWait and return to the default UI.
    Task task = null;
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            task.Wait(timeToWaitMs);
        });

    // Update the UI returning to the valid connection.
    task.ContinueWith(ant =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Connection good to go (retore valid connection update UI etc.)!
                this.toolStripLabelState.Text = "Connected";
            }
            finally
            {
                RefreshDatabaseStructure();
                task.Dispose();
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            mainUiScheduler);
}
```

The problem I have is that `task.Wait(timeToWaitMs);` is causing a `Cursors.WaitCursor` to be displayed - I don't want this. How can I force the error message to be displayed for a period, after which I return to a non-error state?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just remove `task.Wait(timeToWaitMs);`? Starting a task just to let it wait is quite pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a task at all here - at least not without the async features in C# 5. In C# 5 you could just write:

```
await Task.Delay(millisToWait);
```

But until you've got that, I'd just use a timer appropriate for your UI, e.g. [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) or [`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). Just use what you've currently got as a continuation as the "tick" handler for the timer, and schedule it appropriately.

Comment: Okay, but it seems _less neat_ than what I am doing currently. Why does the `async`/`awate` features mean that it is okay - because behined the scenes the compiler is contructing something simalar to the `Task`/`Continuation` structure I have here. As always, thanks for your time Jon.

Comment: @Killercam: In what way is it less neat? You want something to happen in a certain amount of time - that's exactly what a timer is for. async/await allows asynchronous waiting for the completion of anything awaitable, including `Task.Delay`. Basically it's doing something similar to what you're doing now, but considerably more simply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Timer, instead of task.Wait().You can make it wait for an amount of time. Once the timer ticks, a callback can start the update.

```
var timer = new Timer(timeToWaitMs);
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
                              {
                                  timer.Stop();
                                  UpdateValidConnection();
                              };



private void UpdateValidConnection()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try             
        {
            this.toolStripLabelState.Text = "Connected";
        }
        finally
        {
            RefreshDatabaseStructure();
        }
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, mainUiScheduler);
}
```

Comment: I realise this, but I cannot do it the way you have this currently as I do not want to update EVERY `timeToWaitMs` - just when I call the method. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is why I wrote " timer.Stop();" on the Elapsed callback